# How can you get vim to add a header comment to new files?

Tags: comments, vim

I write a lot of Rails apps these days and would like to have vim add header comments to all the code I work on..

I tend to store my projects in

```
~/Development/Repos/Personal
```

And

```
~/Development/Repos/Work
```

Can I get vim to use different copyrights etc based on where abouts the file is being created?

Comment: This question is off topic. It will probably be migrated to a more appropriate SE site. Programmers.SE is not a support forum.

Answer (score 2):

You can just save a header template as a plain text file and read it into a new file with [:read](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#%3aread). As for checking the path, just write a Ruby script to produce the desired text and invoke it with [:read!](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#%3aread!). Creating a true vim plugin is also an option. However, why waste time learning a new language and API when you already know how to deal with text and paths in Ruby? Although, a bash script would create even less friction if you are comfortable with it.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use one of the many snippet plugins, like [XPTemplate](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2611) or [snipMate](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540), to create a 'header' snippet and then use it. The force of these plugins is that you just have to type a word and then press tab to get the expanded snippet.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a snippet from my [vimrc](https://github.com/bheeshmar/dotfiles/blob/master/vim_settings/vimrc) which puts in boilerplate when I create a file named test_something.rb.  You can probably use a similar autocmd to conditionally add the copyright you desire.  You may have to check for the expanded path in the function, but it seems doable with some vimscripting.

```
" Autocommands
autocmd BufNewFile *test*.rb call MakeRubyUnitTester()

"
" Functions
" Fill in the boilerplate for Ruby Unit Tests
function! MakeRubyUnitTester()
    exec "normal irequire 'test/unit'

class TC_Simple < Test::Unit::TestCase"
endfunction
```